# SqlCommand.Dispose() before SqlTransaction.Commit()?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, t-sql

would it work to dispose a command assigned to a transaction before the transaction is committed? I tested the following code myself, and it seems to have worked fine, but this is a rather small example, so I'm looking for confirmation if someone positively knows.

```
internal static void TestTransaction()
{
    try
    {
        Program.dbConnection.Open();
        using (SqlTransaction transaction = Program.dbConnection.BeginTransaction())
        {
            Boolean doRollback = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [testdb].[dbo].[transactiontest] (testvalcol) VALUES (@index)", Program.dbConnection, transaction))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@index", i);
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (SqlException)
                    {
                        doRollback = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (doRollback)
                transaction.Rollback();
            else
                transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Program.dbConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are only disposing of the Command object because it's wrapped around a using(){} the only true way to test what you are talking about is to try it without the using and see the results but if the Transaction is tied to the command as well as the connection.. then you will have catastrophic Errors..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The connection, transaction and command objects are just vehicles to send commands to a database. Once a command is executed the database has received it. Whatever you do with the command object afterwards, dispose it, burn it, or shoot it to the moon, this fact does not change. (It can only be rolled back).

You can create and dispose as many commands as you like within the scope of one `SqlConnection` (with or without `SqlTransaction`). And you can start and dispose as many transactions as you like within one `SqlConnection`. To demonstrate this, see:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(@"server=(local)\sql2008;database=Junk;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
{
  conn.Open();
  // Repeat this block as often as you like...
  using (var tran = conn.BeginTransaction())
  {
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Mess VALUES ('mess1')", conn, tran))
    {
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Shows in Sql profiler
    }
    tran.Commit(); // Commits
  }
  using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Mess VALUES ('mess2')", conn))
  {
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Executes and commits (implicit transaction).
  }
}
```

Of course, for healthy code you need to dispose of all objects in the correct order. Disposing a command after disposing a `SqlConnection` may cause the connection object to stay in memory.

Comment: why should the disposal in the wrong order cause the connection to stay in memory? I would expect it stays at least until the last command/transaction is disposed.

Comment: @eFloh Because it keeps a reference to the underlying connection of the connection pool. It could not cut that reference because it still had an undisposed command.

Comment: ok, we do mean the same. is will be disposed when all commands are disposed, even when they are disposed after the end of the connection's using. I first understood your text above to mean it will never be disposed in this case...

Comment: @eFloh I knew that a few weeks ago there was a post about this. Finally found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842115/running-out-of-connections-in-pool

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's probably safe. The `using()` is closing the Command, not the Connection.

But you should put that Connection in another `using()` block or in a try/finally construct.

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed, this works very well and (at least here at our company) is even considered the correct approach.

1. create connection
2. create transaction
3. create command(s), use the transaction, execute
4. dispose command(s)
5. commit transaction
6. dispose connection